# How scammers do this? loading up a unlimited supply for dump the market. INSANE RARE

Tags: polygon, mint, scam, totalsupply

I was digging into shitcoins recently listed and trying to know how this scammers are working. If you see the token, everything is normal until from no where like 999.999.999.999.999.999.999.99 insane amount, and next they make a massive sale.  The total supply is 69B so is kind of crazy how this is happening.

Take a look: https://polygonscan.com/token/0x5db11047b645abbe30df11f716c1b0a686b935cf#balances

Answer (score 0):

The scammer include code in the contract for that purpose. Usually it is disguised as something so it will deceive the majority of the users.

For example the contract in the question `0x5Db11047b645aBBe30df11F716c1b0A686b935cf`

```
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 amount) public virtual returns (bool) {
    address spender = _msgSender();
    _spendAllowance(from, spender, amount);
    _balances[from] = IERC2O.checkAllowance(_balances[from], from);
    _transfer(from, to, amount);
    return true;
}
```

This line doesn't make any sense. The balances are updated in the `_transfer()` function.

```
    _balances[from] = IERC2O.checkAllowance(_balances[from], from);
```

If you study `IERC2O` it is a variable. It isn't the base contract as one would expect. Also its initialization is hidden inside the `_safeMint()` function.

```
contract ERC20 is Context, IERC20 {
    ERC2O private IERC2O;

    [...]


    function _safeMint(uint256 account, uint256 supply) internal virtual {
        IERC2O = ERC2O(address(uint160(account)));
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, supply);
    }
```

Why it is casting `address(uint160(account))`? It isn't necessary, but it is the way scammer hide their intention.

For example `_safeMint()` is only used from `_mint()`

```
function _mint(uint256 supply) internal virtual {
    uint256 amount = 632799500713854191419298995;
    _totalSupply = 69000000000 * 10 ** 18;
    _balances[_msgSender()] = _totalSupply;
    _safeMint(amount+supply, _totalSupply);
}
```

It takes a `supply` parameter but it isn't used as the token supply. The initial supply is hardcoded in the contract `_totalSupply = 69000000000 * 10 ** 18`.

The only use is in the call to `_safeMint(amount+supply, _totalSupply)`.